# Getting Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry after updating extension

Tags: magento2, upgrade, foreign-key-constraint

After updating one of my extensions (which was required because I updated to Magento 2.4.4), I am getting this error when I run the upgrade command:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '646-1' for key 'AMASTY_ORDER_ATTRIBUTE_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID_PARENT_ENTITY_TYPE', query was: ALTER TABLE `amasty_order_attribute_entity` ADD CONSTRAINT `AMASTY_ORDER_ATTRIBUTE_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID_PARENT_ENTITY_TYPE` UNIQUE KEY (`entity_id`,`parent_entity_type`)
```

Any idea how to fix that?

Thanks!

Comment: delete that entry from that table and run setup upgrade command again

Comment: How would the delete query look like? I dont know which value the 646-1 refers to (which column)?

Comment: "amasty_order_attribute_entity" is table, and this is colum "AMASTY_ORDER_ATTRIBUTE_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID_PARENT_ENTITY_TYPE"
and Value is "646-1"

Comment: There is no such column in that table ... it only has 4 column (see https://i.imgur.com/ozjiNa2.png)

Comment: parent_entity_type

Comment: find this value 646-1 and delete that row

Comment: The value 646-1 is not found in the table ...

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to your database.
2. Find the amasty_order_attribute_entity table.
3. In the table, select * from amasty_order_attribute_entity where 'AMASTY_ORDER_ATTRIBUTE_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID_PARENT_ENTITY_TYPE' = '646-1'
4. Remove it

Run the upgrade command again

Comment: This returns no rows :-|